# What are the names of maven dependencies?

Tags: maven, jboss, jboss6.x

I am trying to deploy my maven application to Jboss eap 6.3. I am supposed to add the dependency names to create the manifest:

```
  <configuration>
     <archive>
        <manifestEntries>
           <Dependencies></Dependencies>
        </manifestEntries>
     </archive>
  </configuration>
```

The question is: what are the names of the dependencies? For example what would be the name of following dependecy:

```
  <dependency>
      <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
       <artifactId>spring-security-taglibs</artifactId>
       <version>3.2.2.RELEASE</version>
  </dependency>
```

Answer (score 3):

It would be `{artifactId}-{version}.jar` for example, for `spring-security-taglibs` dependency the jar name would be `spring-security-taglibs-3.2.2.RELEASE.jar`